# Firebase crashlytics - obfuscation/deobfuscation

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, crashlytics, deobfuscation

If firebase crashlytics can de-obfuscate the code by itself, do we really need to add the following lines to achive de-obfuscation?

```html
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable        # Keep file names and line numbers.
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception  # Optional: Keep custom exceptions.
```

simply adding minifyEnabled:true is enough? or this will leads to partial de-obfuscation?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android